# How to extract signature from function reference in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a function in Python like so:

```
def foo(x): pass
```

According to Python, 'foo' alone is a function reference, right?

```
>>> def foo(x): pass
...
>>> foo
<function foo at 0xb7f3d1b4>
```

Is there any way I can examine the function reference to determine the number of arguments it expects?

Comment: BTW, I see that there's a PEP related to this: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/

Comment: What did `help(foo)` tell you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`inspect.getfullargspec`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec) in py3k or [`inspect.getargspec`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) in earlier versions.

```
 >>> def foo(x): pass

>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(foo)
FullArgSpec(args=['x'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```